# A finite diagram in an abelian category which may not be locally small

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

This question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/applying-freyd-mitchells-embedding-theorem-on-large-categories).
I will use the notations of my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56454/abelian-categories-and-axiom-ab5/165375#165375).

We say a category $\mathcal C$ is locally small if Hom($X, Y$) is small for any $X, Y \in$ Ob($C$).

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category which may not be locally small.
Let $V$ be a finite subset of Ob($\mathcal A$).
Let $T$ be a finite subset of Mor($\mathcal A$) such that both dom($f$) and codom($f$) belong to $V$ for each $f \in T$.
Does there exist an abelian subcategory $\mathcal B$ of $\mathcal A$ satisfying the following conditions?
If yes, how would you prove it?

(1) $\mathcal B$ is small.

(2) $V \subset$ Ob($\mathcal B$) and $T \subset$ Mor($\mathcal B$).

(3) The canonical functor $\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal A$ is exact.

If the answer is affirmative, by [Mitchell's embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell's_embedding_theorem), you can consider the diagram ($V, T$) as that of the category of modules over a ring.
Hence you can use diagram chasing on it.

Comment: Interesting question. I think the answer doesn't change if you replace "locally small" with "small", but I could be wrong. Perhaps you should ask on MO?

Comment: Thanks. I replaced "locally small" with "small".

Comment: I posted this question in MO.
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102616/a-finite-diagram-in-an-abelian-category-which-may-not-be-locally-small